# Put a condition inside a cat in bash

Tags: bash, cat

I am relatively new with bash and I wonder if it is possible to put a condition inside a cat in bash

```
cat > /root/file <<EOL
A line of text
Some other text
EOL
```

Now i want to  put an if condition inside the cat command.For e.g 
 `if [condition] = something` then `Some other text` is written to file.

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Could you just do two `cat` commands? One for `if` the other for `else`?

Comment: I though that was a faster way to do it with only 1 cat...seems there is non:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with `cat` specifically. But you don't have to write everything at once; use append redirection operator `>>`.

```
echo "A line of text" > /root/file
if [ "$FOO" = bar ]
  echo "Another line of text" >> /root/file
fi
```

Or equivalently with `cat`:

```
cat > /root/file <<EOL
A line of text
EOL
if [ "$FOO" = bar ]
  cat >> /root/file <<EOL
Another line of text
EOL
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out **that tabs for EOL** should be brought back to the starting position of the file no matter the tabbing of if statement. This solved a problem I couldn't solve for hours.

Answer (score 3):

No. cat is not a programming language, and bash is not responsible for interpreting (most of) the data sent to it. Consider using something like awk instead.

Answer (score 2):

stumbled upon this thread and wondered if there is something wrong with this (runs on my mac at least):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SLAVEOF="192.168.99.100 6379"
#SLAVEOF=""
cat <<EOL
hello world with some $SLAVEOF
$(if [ "$SLAVEOF" = "" ]; then
    echo "slave was \"\""
else
    echo "slave was $SLAVEOF"
fi)
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not make it with cat, but you can do like this, all output from script after exec will write into /root/file:

```
exec >> /root/file

if [ condition ]; then
    echo line of text
else
    echo another line
fi
```

If you don't want every thing into save file, follow other answers

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out yet another alternative,

```
if condition; then
    cat
else
    grep -vxF 'Some other text'
fi > /root/file <<EOL
A line of text
Some other text
EOL
```